how to setup and run Solar2d on Ubuntu?
I have installed Lua and Solar2d on my ubuntu machine using snap. It runs fine but when I try to open a project or create a new project and try to start emulator, it gives me errors.
rai@rai-ThinkPad-Yoga-260:~/Documents/Solar2D Projects/langraan$ solar2d .
libGL error: MESA-LOADER: failed to open iris: /usr/lib/dri/iris_dri.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory (search paths /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri:\$${ORIGIN}/dri:/usr/lib/dri, suffix _dri)
libGL error: failed to load driver: iris

Copyright (C) 2009-2100  C o r o n a   L a b s   I n c .
        Version: 3.0.0
        Build: 2100.9999
WARNING: Cannot create path for resource file 'resource.car (/snap/solar2d/24/usr/local/bin/Solar2D/Resources/resource.car)'. File does not exist.

Platform: rai-ThinkPad-Yoga-260 / x86_64 / #41~22.04.2-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Mon Jun  3 11:32:55 UTC 2 / llvmpipe (LLVM 12.0.0, 256 bits) / 3.1 Mesa 21.2.6 / 2100.9999 / En:En | nil | En:En | `��
Loading project from: /snap/solar2d/24/usr/local/bin/Solar2D/Resources/homescreen
Project sandbox folder: /home/rai/snap/solar2d/24/.Solar2D/Sandbox/homescreen


I have similar issue. Try to build Solar2d yourself with steps in this link https://forums.solar2d.com/t/how-i-made-solar2d-works-on-linux/356469. In my case it solved the problem.
